# How to show timestamp x-axis in Python Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I want to plot [this data](https://gofile.io/?c=oTDwzL) to evaluate data availability. I used the following plotting code in Plotly.

```
import datetime
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y="variable", color='value', orientation="h",
             hover_data=[df.index],
             height=350,
             color_continuous_scale=['firebrick', '#2ca02c'],
             title='',
             template='plotly_white', 
            )
```

The result is just like what I want below.
[image]

But, the x-index show numbers. I want a timestamp (month+year) on the x-axis, instead.

**Edit**
Adding the fllowing

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title=''), 
                  xaxis=dict(
                      title='Timestamp', 
                      tickformat = '%Y-%b',
                  )
                 )
```

Gives

[image]

which seems that the x-axis is not read from the data index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use bars it seems to me that you need to find a nice workaround. Have you considered to use `Heatmap`?

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_csv("availability3.txt",
                 parse_dates=["Timestamp"])\
       .drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)

# you want to have variable as columns
df = pd.pivot_table(df,
                    index="Timestamp",
                    columns="variable",
                    values="value")
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Heatmap(
        z=df.values.T,
        x=df.index,
        y=df.columns,
        colorscale='RdYlGn',
        xgap=1,
        ygap=2)
      )

fig.show()
```

[image]