# Python horizontal chart for start call time and end call time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need some references how can I make visual analyse of start call, end call.
I have data which I get from database.

soemthing like this

```
data_frame= pd.DataFrame(myresult,columns=['Name','StartCall','EndCall'])
```

dark blue is time when they are talking, light blue when they are not talking...
[image]

SAMPLE Data from Comment

```
 Name            StartCall             EndCall 
 Name  2018-12-14 14:42:24  2018-12-14 14:42:2
```

Comment: sample data: Name           StartCall                                        EndCall
0           Name               2018-12-14 14:42:24                     2018-12-14 14:42:26

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61126999/edit) your questuib to clarify your question

Comment: Maybe via `barh` as for example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60295800/12046409)?

Comment: @JohanC Hi! Thanks for the answer. This is ok, but I was wondering how can I do group by for example name1. Since I have 20 rows for name1 with different periods of start and end time?

Comment: You could make the name column categorical, so each name will be mapped to a number that can be placed on the y-axis

Comment: I guess you are looking for a gantt like solution

Comment: Does something like this help you? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100880/4819376)

Comment: Thanks guys for answers...the main problem here is that I don't see how can I group by data. For exmp. I have 3 rows
Name    StartCallTime    EndCallTime
Mike      '10:32:47 PM',   '10:33:07 PM'
Mike      '10:33:15 PM',   '10:33:25 PM'
Mike      '10:34:51 PM',   '10:34:54 PM'

Need to have name on Y axis, and times on X Axis all in 1 row....

Comment: I dont know how to edit comments, hope that you get my data :D